# Best way to capture a regex from stdout and pipe match into an xarg command

Tags: regex, grep, command-line-interface

I am trying to put together a simple script that does a regex on a git clone output and captions the directory that the default clone cmd is cloning too and then captures this into a shell for or something that can then be piped into xargs?

E.g:

`git clone git@github.com:thorchain/instaswap-sdk.git |& grep "\'\S*\'" | xargs cd`

In this example grep is not the right tool as its output is the matching line and not the match. However, for the life of me, I can't seem to find a simple regex matching tool?

Thanks in adv
Luke

Comment: Add output of your git command and your desired output (no description) to your question.

Comment: If you want to make `grep` output matches, you need to use the `-o` option, `grep -o "\'\S*\'"`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the missing bit was the grep -o that I needed. What I was trying to do was built a bash function the git cloned and cd into the repos directory.

End solution here:

```
function gitc() {
  cd `git clone "$@" |& grep -o "\'\S*\'" | tr -d "'"`
}
```